# facebook comments not appearing on mobile

Tags: facebook, mobile, comments

[Rage Quit Baddie](http://www.ragequitbaddie.com) that is not displaying the comments window from Facebook on a mobile site.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="promote">
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" 
data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  data-num-posts="2"
data-width="470"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.promote{
clear: both;
padding-top: 25px;
}
```

This is a WordPress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="promote">
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" 
data-font="trebuchet ms"></div>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  data-num-posts="2"
data-width="470" mobile="auto-detect"></div>
</div>
```

Try to use the mobile attribute **mobile="auto-detect"** , pls refer this URL and read *Attributes* section - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/